# JavaFX get PieChart Color

Tags: javafx, colors, getcolor

Is there a way to get the default Pie Chart color in JavaFX? I've been looking for solutions but I couldn't get any. I have seen a way to set the color of the Pie Chart, and then work my way to get the Color value. However, I want to just use the default color of the PieChart provided by JavaFX, and just return it so I could use it for something else. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by default color? each pie has its own, it's not available by api but only by css (afair) - search this site, there are some qas a couple of years ago, maybe they still hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaFX 8+ the default CSS theme called Modena and you can find a lot of information in this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470). All the charts are using the same color palette which is :

```
CHART_COLOR_1: #f3622d;
CHART_COLOR_2: #fba71b;
CHART_COLOR_3: #57b757;
CHART_COLOR_4: #41a9c9;
CHART_COLOR_5: #4258c9;
CHART_COLOR_6: #9a42c8;
CHART_COLOR_7: #c84164;
CHART_COLOR_8: #888888;
```

keep in mind that although the link above is a good way to find some properties is always recommended to read the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: The link used for _JavaFX CSS Reference Guide_ is for JavaFX 2.2. A more up-to-date version (JavaFX 10) is located at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Indeed I wasn't paying attention, i though it was the most recent one thanks i will edit my answer.